# Aggregate counts into count object using $group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given:

```
db.invoices.find()

[{"_id":"585c291cb035648543000006","client":"58333caa36f02d14009c50ee","status":"open","amount":150},
{"_id":"585c2906b035648543000005","client":"58333caa36f02d14009c50ee","status":"sent","amount":175},
{"_id":"585c28fbb035648543000004","client":"58333caa36f02d14009c50ee","status":"paid","amount":375},
{"_id":"585c28bab035648543000003","client":"58333caa36f02d14009c50ee","status":"open","amount":400},
{"_id":"585c2872b035648543000001","client":"583335ad36f02d14009c3f88","status":"sent","amount":120},
{"_id":"585c297db035648543000007","client":"583335ad36f02d14009c3f88","status":"paid","amount":150}]
```

What's the best way to aggregate this model so that the sums of each status are returned in an object named counts for each client:

```
[{
    _id: "58333caa36f02d14009c50ee",
    amount: 1100,
    counts: {
        open: 2,
        sent: 1,
        paid: 1
    }
}, {
    _id: "583335ad36f02d14009c3f88",
    amount: 270,
    counts: {
        open: 0,
        sent: 1,
        paid: 1
    }
}]
```

So far I've got the information aggregating correctly but the results are flat and I'm not sure how to get the counts nested as properties of an object named counts:

```
[{
    $project: {
        client: 1,
        status: 1,
        amount: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$client',
        amount: { $sum: '$amount'},
        open: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$status", 'open']
                    },
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        },
        sent: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$status", 'sent']
                    },
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        },
        paid: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$status", 'paid']
                    },
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

which returns:

```
[{
    _id: "58333caa36f02d14009c50ee",
    amount: 1100,
    open: 2,
    sent: 1,
    paid: 1
}, {
    _id: "583335ad36f02d14009c3f88",
    amount: 270,
    open: 0,
    sent: 1,
    paid: 1
}]
```

I assumed I could get these counts nested by defining the fieldname in $group as something like:

```
$group: {
    _id: '$client',
    amount: { $sum: '$amount'},
    "counts.open": {
        $sum: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $eq: ["$status", 'open']
                },
                then: 1,
                else: 0
            }
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

but mongo doesn't allow '.' in any defined fieldname during $group aggregation step. Is this possible to do during mongo aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a final $project step:

```
{
   $project: {
       client: '$_id',
       amount: 1,
       "counts.open": '$open',
       "counts.sent": '$sent',
       "counts.paid": '$paid'
   }
}
```